# How does itertools.combinations scale in Python?

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

I'm doing a brute-force approach to trying to find the combination to an extension to a puzzle.

I am trying to get a large number of combinations and then test each combination to see if they fit certain criteria. 
I generate the combinations using Python's excellent itertools, essentially this gives me an iterator I can go over and test each one.

This returns quickly and gives me **91390** combinations to check:

```
itertools.combinations(range(1, 40), 4)
```

This takes a couple of minutes and give me **198792594** combinations to test:

```
itertools.combinations(range(1, 122), 5)
```

When I get to the next level, I need the answer to this:

```
itertools.combinations(range(1, 365), 6)
```

When I get into 6-way combinations of a set of 364... it takes a very long time. **AGES**. Am I inherently asking for a great deal of combinations? How does it scale?

Comment: This is to solve an extension to Car Talk Puzzle on Oct 22nd. They gave the answer and hinted at a general solution. http://www.cartalk.com/content/puzzler/transcripts/201143/index.html

Comment: The link does not goes to where it should

Comment: Link to [Car Talk Puzzle](http://www.cartalk.com/content/stone-temple-farmers?question) in question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're asking for 365 choose 6 = (365 * 364 * ... * 360) / (6 * 5 * ... * 2 * 1) = 3,151,277,509,380 combinations. That's a *lot*. Looping over 3 trillion elements is just not going to happen on your desktop in Python – no way.

If you're just looking for how many there are supposed to be, the formula to calculate this directly without considering all of them is [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).

Edit: I just looked at the problem, and it seems like you're trying to solve it by considering all possible combinations of weights and seeing if they work. Brute-forcing it clearly isn't going to work in this situation – you'll have to think of a cleverer solution.

Comment: Indeed 'brute force'! Worked fine for the original solution, but I can see it doesn't scale much beyond it. But their 'power of three' general solution does make sense for solutions past 6 pieces. Thanks.

Comment: @deepgeek: In some sense this is a surprising application of a ternary counting system. You could do the same thing with weights in powers of two: 1, 2, 4, 8, 16... just that the requisite stones wouldn't sum to 40kg. (Instead, they sum to a nicer pattern of numbers: *n* such stones sum to a weight of 2^ *n* - 1.)

Answer (score 2):

You calculate these numbers like this:

1. Go to google.com
2. type in "40 choose 4"
3. type in "121 choose 5"
4. type in "[364 choose 6](http://www.google.com/search?q=364%20choose%206)"

See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) for the actual formula.

It scales like the factorial function.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [itertools documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations), the `number of items returned is n! / r! / (n-r)! when 0 <= r <= n or zero when r > n`.

The memory use is small  -- just enough to store the pool of n-items and the r-length result tuple.